# Websocket only works on localhost and fails when deployed to remote server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I am setting up websocket on my node server like so

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8080 });
```

then this code send progress updates of ffmpeg function like so

```
  wss.clients.forEach((client) => {
    client.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'progress', data: progress }));
  });
```

on the client side when using

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.100:8080');
```

it worked just fine I was able to receive the data but when I deploy the server and use

```
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://example.onrender.com');
```

I can no longer receive progress but all other code is running fine

```
ws.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  if (data.type === 'progress') {
    console.log(`Progress: ${data.data}%`);
    this.setState({renderProgress: data.data})
  }
});
```

I tried ws, wss, I had specified port 8080, I also tried port 10000 the one that is running when deployed, pretty much all combinations have been tested but nothing works

Comment: What does your network tab in your dev tools tell you about the status of that socket?

Comment: invalid sec-websocket-accept response

Comment: OK, and the next step would be to search online for that error and see if there are any articles/posts that show you how to solve it.

Comment: genius idea I haven't thought about that